# how can i save and return an object in/from json file?

Tags: vba

i am working on coreldraw v2020 , writing macro and i need to save shape objects in JSON file .
is there any method to write the object directly in the file ?
the programming language is vusial basic

Comment: You would need to decide what properties of the shape were important to you, then figure out (using of of the several VBA/json libraries already available) how to write that information in JSON format.  There's no real shortcut for that.

Comment: I would try to find the simplest similar approach to your problem and try to make that work googling things up. If you get stuck in something concrete, ig you come to stack overflow with concrete simple questions, sure you'll get the help you need